# How do I manually define save paths in GMS?

Tags: game-maker, windows, savegame, settings

I want to know if it is possible to set the path for my game's save data in [GameMaker: Studio](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi6t8HO1LbVAhUBXWMKHQhVAlMQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNHHo70VL1xMWJRtWtvfEl0RBr5QjA) outside of the two default options I am given in the program. The options I get are:

```
%LocalAppData%\<game_name>
```

and

```
%AppData%\<game_name>
```

I can't seem to find a text box or text feild that let's me set something different. I feel like there should be one for advanced users so that path variables and wildcards can be used in the save data path.

I also tried opening the game's config `.gmx` and setting the path there. Unfortunately it did not work as the only values that *do* work are `0` & `1` which represent the default path options respectively. Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try saving it using the [file system](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

*You can't do it.*

### Longer answer:

Game Maker Studio does not support a user-specified path for it's game-saving functionality. **However, what you are trying to do is possible with the [file system API](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/index.html) in [GML](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/).** Without using GML, you are limited to using the default paths for game saves.

Personally, I would use plain text files to save your game data in.

See also:

- [manipulating text files in GML](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/files/index.html)
- [convert real number to string in GML](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/string.html)
- [convert string to real number in GML](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/real.html)

Comment: I thought so, thanks for the info. I _really_ hate when SDKs pull this crap, I don't need my hand held.